# Replace content of SQL file using batch file

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have muliple SQL files (4000+) and each and every file content ends with "/".

suppose, I have persons.sql and the content is

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)/
```

Using batch file I would need to replace the "/" with ";" so that my out put is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

Hope you will help me as I am new to batch file

Comment: @ViktorBardakov it is mentioned 4038

Comment: Could `/` also appear elsewhere in the files? Could there occur any empty lines in the files, and if so, do they have to be preserved?

Comment: @aschipfl I would need to intact each and everything as it is. The only thing i would need to do is to replace the "/" which is at the end of every file.

Note: It is not present anywhere in the file.

Comment: are all the files contained in one folder or they are also in subdirectories?

Comment: @npocmaka YES in a folder

Comment: Unless you are familiar with the content of all 4000+ files, it is a very big assumption that all `/` must be converted, or else that only the `/` at the end of the file should be converted.

Comment: Also, there are already many Q&A that explore how to edit a text file within a Windows batch file.

Comment: Depending on target database, you may be better off issuing a command to change the command terminator from `;` to `/`, and leave all the files alone.

Answer (score 0):

If the last line is always ")/", then this might work. If it might be something else, you could do some substring work to figure it out.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE dissapearingact.txt`) do (
    IF "%%s" EQU ")/" (
        ECHO ^);
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO %%s
    )
)
EXIT /B 0
```